# uwp Segoe MDL2 icons, why no bell/alert icon

Tags: uwp, notifications, icons, alert

I searched for bell/alert/notification icon in Segoe MDL2 icons. I couldn't find it, is creating own bell icon only option or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `RingerBadge12 (EDAC)` look enough like a bell/notification icon?

Otherwise you could look at `ActionCenterNotification (E7E7)`

Comment: Yes Ringer looks ok

Comment: Is it possible to use segoe font as symbol? I want to add ring icon in navigationview menu item

Answer (score 1):

On propery Icon of element AppBarButton (and similars) you can only set Enum Icons. To use Segoe MDL2 Assets just do as follows:

```
<AppBarButton>
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xEA8F;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

P.S. upvote if it helped you :)